# Variable Change callback

Tags: javascript, three.js

is there a way to declare a function when a variable change? In the code below, I have declared a function named loadImage that returns the material of the image. However, if this code runs, the declaration of mesh and scene.add(mesh) will runs before the image has been loaded. Is there a way to wait for the variable to finish loading before the other commands are run? Thanks! ^u^

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var materialimg = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
var materialimg = loadImage("test/map.jpg", manager);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialimg);
scene.add(mesh);
```

For reference, here is the LoadImage function:

```
function loadImage(imagePath, loadingManager){
var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(loadingManager);

//create a texture
var texture = new THREE.Texture();

loader.load(imagePath, function(image){
    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpadte = true;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    material.map = texture;

    return material;
});   
}
```

Here is the complete function of the function that calls LoadImage:

```
function testImage(){
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total){
    console.log(item,loaded,total);
    }

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
    var materialimg = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    var materialimg = loadImage("test/map.jpg", manager);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialimg);
    scene.add(mesh);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a callback function like this:

```
function loadImage(imagePath, loadingManager){
    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(loadingManager);

    //create a texture
    var texture = new THREE.Texture();

    loader.load(imagePath, function(image){
        texture.image = image;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
    });   

    return new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: true });
} 

function testImage(){
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total){
        console.log(item,loaded,total);
    }

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
    var materialimg = loadImage("test/map.jpg", manager);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialimg);
    scene.add(mesh);
}
```

EDIT: modified above code. Note that you can't use `return` in a callback function, because it will execute in an other context.

Comment: Should we declare the loadImage function with the callback as a parameter? Moreover, I am assigning "materialimg" to the value that LoadImage returns, how to I go about doing that?

Comment: why do you want to return the `materialimg`? the above code should do exactly the same as your code. the code just moved into a callback function. I don't know a other way than using a callback for your problem.

Comment: I make LoadImage a function that returns a material of the loaded filename, to which I will assign it to materialimg. Then, I will form a mesh with geometry and materialimg. I understand that I need to use callback, but I am not really sure how.

Comment: I have updated the question so as to make things clear. Thanks for your willingness to help!

Comment: no problem ;-) I want reputation points when I solve your problem :D

Comment: dont we all want that! Ok! I will make that answer correct if it works and ofc you'll get like 15 if im not wrong!